# How we can use repeat function with python tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

```
# ==================================================
# Image processing
# ==================================================
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

batch_size = 32

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = batch_size,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

CNN_Classifier.fit(training_set.repeat(),
                    steps_per_epoch=int(7000/batch_size),
                    epochs= 10,
                    validation_data=test_set.repeat(),
                    validation_steps=int(2000/batch_size))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW1CS.png)

I want to know how may i use repeat function in tensorflow and will not get this sort of an error, and in that image I got an error you can check this.

Comment: What repeat function are you talking about? ImageDataGenerator does not have such function.

Comment: I want to repeat the directory image data, which will start from the particular mark where does it's stop at last